# Fastest possible optimisation of an area difference with a constrained sum

Tags: python, performance, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have four arrays, a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>3</sub>,a<sub>4</sub>, each of length 500. I have a target array a<sub>t</sub>, also of length 500. These arrays each represent the y coordinates of unevenly spaced points on a graph. I have the x coordinates in a separate array.

I want to optimise the coefficients c<sub>1</sub>,c<sub>2</sub>,c<sub>3</sub>,c<sub>4</sub> such that the area difference between c<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + c<sub>3</sub>x<sub>3</sub> + c<sub>4</sub>x<sub>4</sub> and a<sub>t</sub> is minimised. The coefficients must sum to 1 and be between 0 and 1 inclusive.

I currently do this using scipy.optimize.minimize. Using scipy.optimize.LinearConstraints, I constrain my target variable (an array [c<sub>1</sub>,c<sub>2</sub>,c<sub>3</sub>,c<sub>4</sub>]) to sum to 1. The loss function multiplies the target variable by the arrays a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>3</sub>,a<sub>4</sub>, and then finds the absolute difference between this sum and a<sub>t</sub>. This absolute difference is integrated between each consecutive pair of x coordinates, and the sum of these integrals is outputted.

Here is the code:

```py
xpoint_diffs = xpoints[1:] - xpoints[:-1]
a1a2a3a4 = np.array([a1,a2,a3,a4])

def lossfunc(x):
   abs_diff = abs(at - (a1a2a3a4 * x).sum(axis = 1))
   return ((absdiff[:-1] + absdiff[1:])/2 * xpoint_diffs).sum()
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

I then pass my constraint and loss function into scipy.optimize.minimize.

Comment: Just a small optimization: You can pull the division by 2 in the last line into the ```xpoint_diffs```. Then you can rewrite it into into a single ```np.dot``` which should be faster: ```return np.dot(absdiff[:-1] + absdiff[1:], half_xpoint_diffs)```

Comment: The ```(a1a2a3a4 * x).sum(axis = 1)``` can also be optimized into a single matrix vector product. However, I'm currently a bit confused about the shapes. ```a1a2a3a4``` should be shape ```(4, 500)``` and ```x``` shape ```(4,)```, right? But that does not broadcast. I guess ```x``` is ```(4, 1)```?

Comment: Using `abs` inside one of your functions makes your optimization problem non-differentiable and thus it violates the mathematical assumptions of most algorithms under the hood of scipy's `minimize`. Just square the expression on the right hand side of abs_diff. That said, the performance of solving a nonlinear optimization problem depends on: a) your initial guess b) your used algorithm c) the implementation of your functions d) how you calculate the derivatives (exact vs approximation by finite differences. Providing a full minimal **reproducible** example would make it easier for us to help.

Comment: @Homer512 that's a good point, thank you. I will turn them both into dot products. Yes, the shape of x is (4,1), you are correct.

Comment: @joni This is essentially my example. I test this using numpy.random.rand matrices of (500,1) to produce ```a1,a2,a3,a4,at```. I don't select an algorithm, and the implementation of my functions is as above. I don't calculate any derivatives and my initial guess is super simple - just (0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25) in this case.

Comment: But if ```a1a2a3a4``` is shape ```(4, 500)``` and ```x``` is shape ```(4, 1)```, then ```(a1a2a3a4 * x).sum(axis=1)``` is shape ```(4, )```. Don't you need shape ```(500, )``` to then integrate the individual line segments?

Comment: I suspect this is actually an LP (after linearizing the abs(.) function). Obviously, an LP solver should be the fastest for an LP problem.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen how would I go about making this problem linear? I know it's convex, but the squared term is throwing me off.

Comment: The loss function is piecewise linear in x (due to the abs(.)) but can be linearized using standard techniques. The result is a linear model (i.e. an LP). I don't see any squared term. I am looking at your lossfunc(x) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a full solution, more like some thoughts that may lead to one. Also, someone please double-check my math.

### Variables and test data

First, let's begin by defining some test data. While doing so, I transpose the `a1a2a3a4` matrix because it will prove more conventient. Plus, I'm renaming it to `a14` because I cannot be bothered writing the whole thing all the time, sorry.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg, random
from scipy import optimize

a14 = random.uniform(-1., 1., (500, 4)) * (0.25, 0.75, 1., 2.)
at = random.uniform(-1., 1., 500)
xpoints = np.cumsum(random.random(500))
initial_guess = np.full(4, 0.25)
```

### Target

Okay, here is my first slight point of confusion: OP described the target as the "area difference" between two graphs. X coordinates are given by `xpoints`. Y coordinates of the target are given as `at` and we search `coeffs` so that `a14 @ coeffs` gives Y coordinates close to the target.

Now, when we talk "area under the graph", my first instinct is piecewise linear. Similar to the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) this gives us the formula `sum{(y[i+1]+y[i]) * (x[i+1]-x[i])} / 2`.
We can reformulate that a bit to get something of the form `(y[0]*(x[1]-x[0]) + y[1]*(x[2]-x[0]) + y[2]*(x[3]-x[1]) + ... + y[n-1]*(x[n-1]-x[n-2])) / 2`. We want to precompute the `x` differences and scaling factor.

```py
weights = 0.5 * np.concatenate(
         ((xpoints[1] - xpoints[0],),
         xpoints[2:] - xpoints[:-2],
         (xpoints[-1] - xpoints[-2],)))
```

These factors are different from the ones OP used. I guess they are integrating a piecewise constant function instead of piecewise linear? Anyway, switching between these two should be simple enough so I leave this here as an alternative.

### Loss function

Adapting OP's loss function to my interpretation gives

```py
def loss(coeffs):
    absdiff = abs(at - (a14 * coeffs).sum(axis=1))
    return (absdiff * weights).sum()
```

As I've noted in comments, this can be simplified by using matrix vector multiplications.

```py
def loss(coeffs):
    return abs(a14 @ coeffs - at) @ weights
```

This is the same as `abs((a14 * weights[:, np.newaxis]) @ coeffs - (at * weights)).sum()` which in turn makes it obvious that we are talking about minimizing the L1 norm.

```py
a14w = a14 * weights[:, np.newaxis]
atw = at * weights
def loss(coeffs):
    return linalg.norm(a14w @ coeffs - atw, 1)
```

This isn't a huge improvement as far as computing the loss function goes. However, it goes a long way towards pressing our problem into a regular pattern.

### Approximate solution

As noted in comments, the `abs()` function in the L1 norm is poison for optimization because it is non-differentiable. If we switch to an L2 norm, we basically have a least squares fit with additional constraints. Of course this is somewhat unsound as we start solving a different, if closely related, problem. I suspect the solution would be "good enough"; or it could be the starting solution that is then polished to conform with the actual target.

In any case, we can use [`scipy.optimize.lsq_linear`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html) as a quick and easy solver. However, that one does not support linearity constraints. We can mimic that with a regularization parameter.

```py
def loss_lsqr(coeffs):
    return 0.5 * linalg.norm(a14w @ coeffs - atw)**2

grad1 = a14w.T @ a14w
grad2 = a14w.T @ at
def jac_lsqr(coeffs):
    return grad1 @ coeffs - grad2

regularization = loss_lsqr(initial_guess) # TODO: Pick better value
a14w_regular = np.append(a14w, np.full((1, 4), regularization), axis=0)
atw_regular = np.append(atw, regularization)
approx = optimize.lsq_linear(a14w_regular, atw_regular, bounds=(0., 1.))

# polish further, maybe?
bounds = ((0., 1.),) * 4
constraint = optimize.LinearConstraint(np.ones(4), 1., 1.)
second_guess = approx.x
second_guess /= linalg.norm(second_guess) # enforce constraint
exact = optimize.minimize(
        loss_lsqr, second_guess, jac=jac_lsqr,
        bounds=bounds, constraints=constraint)
```

Comment: This is incredibly interesting and I'm going to spend my time now trying to understand what you've written. Thanks so much for putting your time and effort into it.

Comment: Since writing this question I've found an analytical way to solve this problem using cvxpy: essentially, performing the minimization of ```((at - (a1a2a3a4 @ c1c2c3c4))**2 @ xpoints)```. This is much slower than scipy.optimize.minimize, but gives _the_ answer.

Comment: @milandeleev That is not solving it analytically at all, but rather numerically.  Note that the solutions will be different from an L1 objective.

Comment: @milandeleev Are you talking about this approach? http://ash-aldujaili.github.io/blog/2016/09/01/lp-norm-min/ Sounds reasonable. If you could put your own answer with your code, I would be interested to see the implementation